How to use AsyncSession.sync_session or how to have both sync and async session with the same scope of objects, single transaction?
I'd like to use AsyncSession.sync_session but the code below fails with error. The code is a simplified version of real case.
import sqlalchemy as sa
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, select
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, async_sessionmaker, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
    
app = FastAPI()
metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)
engine = create_async_engine(
    "postgresql+asyncpg://postgres:postgres@localhost:5433/portal-podrjadchika-local", echo=True
)
SessionLocal = async_sessionmaker(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False)


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True, index=True)
    first_name = sa.Column(sa.String)
    last_name = sa.Column(sa.String)


async def get_session() -> AsyncSession:
    session = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield session
        await session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        await session.rollback()
        raise e
    finally:
        await session.close()


@app.on_event("startup")
async def on_startup() -> None:
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.drop_all)
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)


@app.post('/users')
async def get_users(session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session)):
    stmt = select(User)
    print(session.sync_session.scalars(stmt))  # fails with error sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xd2s)
    return "user"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("so:app", reload=True)

Traceback:
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application Traceback (most recent call
last):   File
"/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 408, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py",
line 84, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py",
line 1054, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/applications.py",
line 123, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py",
line 186, in __call__
    raise exc   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py",
line 164, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 65, in __call__
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)   File
"/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py",
line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py",
line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py",
line 756, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py",
line 776, in app
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py",
line 297, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py",
line 77, in app
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, request)(scope, receive, send)   File
"/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py",
line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py",
line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py",
line 72, in app
    response = await func(request)   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py",
line 278, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py",
line 191, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/fstp/so.py", line
50, in get_users
    print(session.sync_session.scalars(stmt))   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
line 2337, in scalars
    return self._execute_internal(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
line 2120, in _execute_internal
    result: Result[Any] = compile_state_cls.orm_execute_statement(   File
"/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/context.py",
line 293, in orm_execute_statement
    result = conn.execute(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
line 1412, in execute
    return meth(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py",
line 483, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
line 1635, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
line 1844, in _execute_context
    return self._exec_single_context(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
line 1984, in _exec_single_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
line 2342, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    raise exc_info[1].with_traceback(exc_info[2])   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
line 1965, in _exec_single_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py",
line 921, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py",
line 561, in execute
    self._adapt_connection.await_(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py",
line 116, in await_only
    raise exc.MissingGreenlet( sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was
IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at:
https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xd2s)

How can I fix the error? Or how to have both sync and async session with the same scope of objects, single transaction? I need it to make Factory Boy https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/orms.html#sqlalchemy use sync session to instanciate objects.

Because you are using async session you need to await the method.
@app.post('/users')
async def get_users(session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session)):
    stmt = select(User)
    result = await session.scalars(stmt)
    users = result.all()  # Fetch all the users
    return users

For the factory-boy part it doesn't need to be the same transaction or session to use it. You just need to use the same database. To do that just update _create a method in factory:
    @classmethod
    def _create(cls, model_class, *args, **kwargs):
        with some_sync_session() as session:
           session.expire_on_commit = False
           obj = model_class(*args, **kwargs)
           session.add(obj)
           session.commit()
           session.expunge_all()
        return obj

some_sync_session is just sessionmaker which points to the correct database.
I did the similar stuff when I was writing tests for my package. You can check how I set up model factory here at github.

You say: 'For the factory-boy part it doesn't need to be the same transaction or session to use it. You just need to use the same database.' After single test how created data are being erased?

I also did the same in my project. You can check fixture file in github https://github.com/ViAchKoN/dataclass-sqlalchemy-mixins/blob/master/tests/conftest.py.
Feel free to ask more question.

Now I see. You create and drop all tables every single test.

Yep, this is correct. You can this blueprint in your project.

This is interesting. I haven't thought about running tests in this manner. Thanks a lot.

No problem! If you will need to do filtering and sorting in your API please also check my package.  The tests are sent you were done as part of it. I hope you will find it useful https://github.com/ViAchKoN/dataclass-sqlalchemy-mixins
